# GWT - celltable

Tags: gwt

I have a celltable which contains numbers in each column. Is there a way to add an extra row at the end of the celltable..which will show the sum of each column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the celltable has this constructor

```
 void   addColumn(Column<T,?> col, Header<?> header, Header<?> footer) 
          Adds a column to the table with an associated header and footer.
```

You can pass in your customr footer that sums up the values for all the rows.